# Renaming file and attaching to outlook

Tags: windows, batch-file, outlook, batch-rename

I have a batch file collecting some user machine data.  At the end I want to rename the file test.txt to %username%%date%time%.txt.  The code I found on other sites will not rename the file.  What am I missing?

```
ren "c:\users\%username%\Desktop\test.txt" "%username%-%date:~-4,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%time:~-11,2%%time:`-8,2%.txt"
```

This line below is to attach the renamed file above to a new Outlook message with a .zip folder.  Am I off base here as well?

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Outlook.exe" /a "c:\users\%username%\Desktop\"%username%-%date:~-4,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%time:~-11,2%%time:`-8,2%.txt"
```

Comment: The very last part of your rename is using the wrong character. Change `%time:`-8,2%.txt` to `%time:~-8,2%.txt`. Also, in the second line, you have an extra `"` after Desktop\

Comment: @SomethingDark You were correct.  I totally missed that.  Thanks for the fresh set of eyes.  I am trying to submit your response as the answer but I don't see how yet.

Comment: Oh, I added this as a comment instead of an answer. Hang on a second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very last part of your rename is using the wrong character. Change

```
%time:-8,2%.txt`
```

to

```
%time:~-8,2%.txt
```

Also, in the second line, you have an extra " after Desktop\